# Rails' respond_to - syntax analysis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a Rails code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml { render :xml => @users }
  format.json { render :json => @users }
end
```

I know what it does. But I don't know the meaning of the commands **syntax**-wise.

1. `format.xml` -- what is `xml`, is this a method which an object `format` has, correct? Where do I find its signature (or description)?
2. `{ }` -- a block or a hash? I think this is a block.
3. `render` -- a method? where do I find its signature (where in api docs)?
4. `:xml => @users` -- a hash, where `:xml =>` is a key, correct?

So it could be reprented as, right?:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml do
    render(:xml => @users)
  end 
  format.json do
    render(:json => @users)
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you checked out apidock.com ? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492362/rails-how-does-the-respond-to-block-work

Comment: All your assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### format.*

Using the debugger, I learnt that `format` is an instance of `ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector`. It includes `AbstractController::Collector`, which uses [`method_missing`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) to respond to various format calls.

```
if Mime::SET.include?(mime_constant)
  AbstractController::Collector.generate_method_for_mime(mime_constant)
  send(symbol, &block)
else
  # ...
```

#### { render xml: ... }

Looking at `method_missing`, it's clear that it expects a block.

#### render

Yes, render is a method. [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render).

#### :xml => @user

Yes, it's a hash. The key is the symbol `:xml`. It can also be written as

```
render xml: @user

render(xml: @user)

render({xml: @user})
render({:xml => @user})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `format` comes from the request made to the method, `http://app.com/controller/method.format` where format could be `.html` or `.csv` etc. The meaning of `format.xml` is simply to check if the user requested an xml page (`http://app.com/controller/method.xml`.
2. Block, just like you describe.
3. At the apidock! http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render
4. Correct, render will act depending on the key that exists. In your case, as the existing key is `:xml` the render method will output `@users` formatted as XML.