# Return a javascript file from a url in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-worker

I got a `sw.js` file generated by [offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) in 'app/public/packs/'.
I have to respond to a GET to `/sw.js` with `app/public/packs/sw.js`.
No `redirect_to`, I have to serve it from there to have the service worker controlling the root scope.

How do I write a controller to respond to `localhost/sw.js` with the content from `localhost/packs/sw.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `send_file` from the controller action [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233021/returning-files-from-rails) :

```
def your_action 
  send_file("#{Rails.root}/app/public/packs/sw.js",
            :filename => "sw.js",
            :type => "application/javascript")
end
```

I'm not 100% sure on the mime type, it's either `text/javascript` or `application/javascript`

Comment: This is a good answer but now I realized that my problem wasn't the controller but the routes. 

In my `routes.rb` i've added `get '/sw' => 'sw#show'` but:  

`GET localhost/sw.js`   gives No route matches [GET] "/sw.js"  

But `GET localhost/sw` return the correct file. What should I change?

Comment: @lellefood You can add something like the [respond_to and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600864/rails-respond-to-blocks-and-format) block