# Render exception alert in rescue_from using respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, rescue

I'm rescuing an unauthorized exception, and want to render an alert within this rescue block.  Since this is in my application controller, this rescue could be hit in multiple formats, so I need a `respond_to` block.

If I do this without a `respond_to`, everything works fine.  The status is set to 401, and I see the proper exception message flashed.

```
render :json => exception.message, :status => 401
```

However, if I do the same thing inside a `repond_to` block, nothing works.  Status doesn't get set, and the exception message doesn't get rendered.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => exception.message, :status => 401 }
end
```

What could be the problem here?  I've looked through a ton of examples, and this seems like it should work, but the status and message seem to be ignored.

Comment: In the 1st variant you render response to all the requests to controller action despite what their format is. Second variant defines response only for json format requests, e.g. `/example/new.json`. If you make a request to your action like this `/example/new` it will fallback to html format for which you don't define any status and message. See this question and answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492362/rails-how-does-the-respond-to-block-work

Answer (score 0):

Besides you are rendering a json with

```
render :json => exception.message, :status => 401
```

You are answering to HTML requests... So if you need to render it on browsers, you need to handle all format yourself...

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { ... }
  format.html { ... }
end
```

Comment: I mean... the way you are asking, I guess you only have problems testing it on your browser... if not hitting the endpoint with the `.json` format at the end... like `/controller/action.json`