# Route to different action based on format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to route to different controller action based on the format i.e.
/phones/1.json goes to a different action and /phones/1 to different

I want for example GET `/phones/1.json` to go to `show_json` action and GET `/phones/1` to `show` action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`respond_to`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492362/rails-how-does-the-respond-to-block-work) is for:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { show_json }
  format.html
end
```

If you explicitly want different actions, which is contrary to Rails conventions, then you need to add [route constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
get 'phones/:id.:format', constraints: { format: 'json' }, to: '...#show_json'
get 'phones/:id', to: '...#show'
```

This really breaks the Rails model of having a singular controller action per REST action, so I'd advise against it.

You *should* have a `resources :phones` route which takes care of all the defaults for you. You can use `respond_to` to trigger any custom behaviour from there.